# SSRS Date Expression 'Mo 07.12.2015'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to show the yesterday date in my report and it works:

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(dd,-1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())), 105) AS 'Yesterday'
```

--> `06-12-2015`

But I would like to show the day label too, like this:

--> `Sunday 06-12-2015`

How can I add the day label?

Comment: Also you can simply return the date to SSRS and format the way it is presented there using a Format string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Mikey's apporach is the best if you want this as a date value in exports to Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Like this.

```
 select datename(dw, DATEADD(dd,-1, GETDATE())) + ' ' +
 CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(dd,-1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())), 105) AS Yesterday
```

Comment: this only gives the day label